# Prohibition of entering abandoned property?

Tags: halal-haram, property

I'd like to know if entering abandoned buildings fun is prohibited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not exactly the same as entering an abandoned building, there's a Qur'an verse which describes how one should enter another's house:

> O you who have believed, do not enter houses other than your own houses until you ascertain welcome and greet their inhabitants. That is best for you; perhaps you will be reminded.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 24:27](https://quran.com/24/27)</sub>

Here we need permission to enter (which is unsurprising, really).  There's also a hadith which applies to entering without permission:

> The order of taking permission to enter has been enjoined because of that sight, (that one should not look unlawfully at the state of others).
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6241](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/15)</sub>

So sneaking into houses is forbidden, and there seems no reason to believe Allah would have a different stance towards other property.

Moreover, sneaking into buildings would be considered [trespassing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass), and is probably illegal.  Muslims are required to obey the law of the land ([Darul Iftaa](http://daruliftaa.com/node/5852)).  There may also be matters such as safety to take into account: i.e., there might be guard dogs, or maybe some of the structures may collapse.

Sneaking into buildings to use their paid services would be considered [theft of services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft_of_services) and is probably just as illegal as theft of goods.  Another form of using services without paying is considered haram:

> It is not permissible to use public transportation without paying the fees if there are tickets for it.
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=347563)</sub>